# How to declare array string with unknown size(input later)

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create a code that takes the inputs from the user, which is mark and name as an array. I wanted store name from the user in the array so I can use it later. The size of the array needs to be equal to the number of student which we will took from the user.
The problem is I couldn't declare and take those name from the user as an array, it worked as an integer and char before. Please point out where I am wrong.
Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string* name;
    int id;
    int *mark;
    
    ~Student(){
        delete [] mark;
    }
};

void inputStudent(Student* ptr);
void printStudent(Student* pStu);
int markNumber;
int studentNumber;
int i;

int main () {
    Student stu;
    Student* stuPtr = &stu;
    
    stu.mark = new int[markNumber];
    stu.name = new string[studentNumber];
    
    cout << "How many students are there? ";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    
    cout << "How many marks are there? ";
    cin >> markNumber;

    inputStudent(&stu);
    printStudent(&stu);
}

void inputStudent(Student* ptr) {
    for (i = 0; i < studentNumber; i++ ) {
        
        cout << "Please enter a name : ";
        cin >> ptr -> name[i];
        
        cout << "Please enter an id : ";
        cin >> ptr -> id;
        
        for ( i = 0; i < markNumber; i++){
            cout << "Please enter a mark : ";
            cin >> ptr -> mark[i];
        }
    }
}

void printStudent(Student* pStu) {
    cout << "Student info : " << endl;
    cout << "Name : " << pStu -> name << endl;
    cout << "Id : " << pStu -> id << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < markNumber; i++){
        cout << "Mark " << i << " : " << pStu -> mark[i] << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You almost never want to use `new` as with using it comes a great deal of responsibility. Consider using a resizable container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: You're using dynamic memory allocation (operator `new`) directly.   That's unnecessary.   Use the `std::vector` class (from standard header `<vector>`) instead.

Comment: You dont initialize markNumber and studentNumber before use

Comment: @marcinj I try it but it seem doesn't work